# What type of stochastic process satisfy $\mathrm{Var}[X_t]\mathrm{Var}[X_s] = \mathrm{Cov}[X_t,X_s]$ for all $t,s \in \mathbb R^+$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}$ be an $L^2$ stochastic process. What does it say about $X$ if $\mathrm{Var}[X_t]Var[X_s] = \mathrm{Cov}[X_t,X_s]$ for all $t,s \in \mathbb R^+$ ? What does it says about $X$ if $\mathrm{Var}[X_t]\mathrm{Var}[X_s] \neq \mathrm{Cov}[X_t,X_s]$ for all $t,s \in \mathbb R^+$ ?

Is there a special class of processes that satisfy one of the above ?

Now we repeat the same questions, but we suppose that $X$ is a Gaussian process. Do we learn something new ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $s=t$ the condition is
$$\mathrm{Var}(X_s)=\mathrm{Var}(X_s)^2,$$
which forces, that
$\mathrm{Var}(X_s)=1$ for all $s$. And thus
$$\mathrm{Cov}(X_s,X_t) = 1^2 = \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X_s)}\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X_t)},$$
which implies, that the correlation between $X_s$ and $X_t$ is $1$ for all $s$ and $t$, and therefore $X_t$ is almost surely a linear function of $X_s$, that is
$$X_t = aX_s + b$$
for some $a$ and $b$. It is clear from the covariance condition, that $a=1$ and we can see, that $b=\mathbb{E}[X_t - X_s]$. Thus we may write
$$X_t = X_0 + f(t),$$
where $f(t)$ is the deterministic function $f(t)=\mathbb{E}[X_t-X_0]$. Also any proces defined as $X_t := X_0 + f(t)$ with $\mathrm{Var}(X_0)=1$ and $f$ some arbitrary function, will satisfy the given condition.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you can have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3921012/what-type-of-stochastic-process-satisfy-varx-tvarx-s-covx-t-x-s-for-al It is nearly the same, but we cannot take t=s