# What type of stochastic process satisfy $\operatorname{Var}[X_t]\operatorname{Var}[X_s] = \operatorname{Cov}[X_t,X_s]$ for all $s<t \in \mathbb R^+$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Related question: [What type of stochastic process satisfy $Var[X_t]Var[X_s] = Cov[X_t,X_s]$ for all $t,s \in \mathbb R^+$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3920219/what-type-of-stochastic-process-satisfy-varx-tvarx-s-covx-t-x-s-for-al/3920274#3920274) I asked this question, which is nearly the same as this one (but as important).

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb R^+}$ be an $L^2$ stochastic process. What does it say about $X$ if $\operatorname{Var}[X_t]\operatorname{Var}[X_s] = \operatorname{Cov}[X_t,X_s]$ for all $s<t  \in \mathbb R^+$ ? What does it says about $X$ if $\operatorname{Var}[X_t]\operatorname{Var}[X_s] \neq \operatorname{Cov}[X_t,X_s]$ for all $s<t  \in \mathbb R^+$ ?

Is there a special class of processes that satisfy one of the above ?

Now we repeat the same questions, but we suppose that $X$ is a Gaussian process. Do we learn something new ?

Comment: I am ignorant about this topic, but if this equation holds for probability distributions, doesn't it imply that they are independent random variables?  And that therefore $ X_t $ does not depend on $ X_s $?

Comment: I believe this question is a subset of your previous question: here, you're assuming that $s<t$, whilst in the previous question we assumed generic $s$ and generic $t$. The answer to your previous question should still be applicable to this question.

Comment: @JanStuller : I agree

Comment: @JanStuller No because the previous answer uses precisely $t=s$